# JS: Benchmark a Bidirectional Map algorithm

Tags: javascript, dictionary, benchmarking

I've implemented a kind of Bidirectional Map in JS. It can store two lists (left and right) and can store relations between two sides, holding additional data. Example :

```
let ingredients = 'apple chocolate vanilla'.split(' ')
let desserts = 'cheesecake blackforest'.split(' ')

ingredients.forEach((i) => { bdm.ladd(i, i)})
desserts.forEach((d) => { bdm.radd(d, d)})

bdm.join('apple', 'cheesecake', '4')
bdm.join('chocolate', 'blackforest', '200g')
bdm.join('vanilla', 'cheesecake', '1g')
bdm.join('vanilla', 'blackforest', '2.5g')

// query again structure
bdm.seek('vanilla', null, (assoc) => { console.log(assoc) })

// output:
// { left: 'vanilla', right: 'chesscake', data: '1g'}
// { left: 'vanilla', right: 'blackforest', data: '2.5g'}
```

since my bidimap is implemented with Maps of Maps, it is supposed to be time-constant. I want to proove it by benchmarking it.

I wish to use benchmark.js to measure it.

```
let sizes = [10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000]
let density = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100] // percentages

sizes.forEach((s) => {
  density.forEach((d) => {
      // START TIMER
      // generatte a S items list (left)
      // generatte a S items list (rightt)
     // store list in map
     // association items left * right with a robability of 1 / D
     // END TIMER

     // REPORT (LOG) size * density --> time
  })
})
```

How to write proper tests with the lib benchmarks.js ?

AND:

How to evaluate memory footprint  of the data structuere ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please add `bdm` as well.

Comment: OK... feel free to browse the repo: https://github.com/hefeust/ecmasy for more details